# Table middle height text in one column. No multirows, no known height

Tags: tables, alignment, vertical

I am completely new to LaTex.

Due to plenty of text in the second and third column of the table, the height of the row is increased. How do I get the text in the first row (not a lot of text) to be in the middle, vertically? I will be increasing the table and each row will have a different height, which I do not want to specify each single time.

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Full-model chemical reactions ($vf$: forward reaction, $vr$:reverse reaction)}
    \label{table:fullmodel_rxns}
    \hskip-1cm
    \begin{tabular}{cll} 
        \toprule
        \textbf{Chemical Reaction} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Reaction Rates}} \\
        
        \midrule
 \ce{-> sg$1$} & \shortstack{induction of synthesis\\ of sgRNA1 by Arabinose}
     & \shortstack{$vf = Ara*(1-bSG1)*VMAX*$\\$(30 - sg5dCasGA - sg6dCasGA)$}\\
        \midrule
 \ce{-> sg$1$} & \shortstack{basal levels of sgRNA1\\ w/o Arabinose}
     & \shortstack{$vf = (bSG1)*VMAX*$\\$(30 - sg5dCasGA - sg6dCasGA)$}\\
        \midrule
\ce{sg$i$ ->}  & \shortstack{degradation of sgRNAi\\ $i={1,2,3,4,5,6}$}
     & \shortstack{$vf = (dmRNAcaseF)*sgi$}\\
 \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:dvar}%
\end{table}%
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome top TeX:SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with this table, For help you wee need to know, which `\documentclass` you use, page layout and used packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]

- Based on guessing which `\documentclass` you use, what is document pages layout, etc.
- With use `tblr˛table, defined in` tabularray` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Full-model chemical reactions ($vf$: forward reaction, $vr$:reverse reaction)}
\label{table:fullmodel_rxns}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} Q[l,m] 
                            X[0.8, l, m]  
                            X[1.2, l, m, mode=math] @{}},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, mode=text, c},
             row{3-Z} = {abovesep=5pt}
             }
    \toprule
{Chemical\\ Reaction}   
    &   Description   
        &   Reaction Rates    \\
    \midrule
\ce{-> sg$1$} 
    &   induction of synthesis of sgRNA1 by Arabinose 
        &   vf = Ara*(1-bSG1)*VMAX*(30 - sg5dCasGA - sg6dCasGA)   \\
%        \midrule
\ce{-> sg$1$} 
    &   basal levels of sgRNA1 w/o Arabinose
        &   vf = (bSG1)*VMAX*   
            (30 - sg5dCasGA - sg6dCasGA)        \\
%        \midrule
\ce{sg$i$ ->}  
    &   degradation of sgRNAi   $i={1,2,3,4,5,6}$
        &   vf = (dmRNAcaseF)*sgi               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\label{tab:dvar}    % why two labels?
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Off-topic:**
I'm not familiar with used symbols in your math, but it seems that you not care about distinguish between variables and operators, the same problem is multi letters variables. For example

- $vf$ ---> $\mathit{vf}$
- $vf$ ---> $\mathit{vf}$
- $dmRNA$ ---> $\mathrm{dmRNA}$
- $VMAX$ --->  $\mathrm{VMAX}$ or maybe $V_{\max}$?

but in math expressions are more similar cases which meanings are unknown to me, so I can't give any advice, how to handle with them.

[image]

I suggest you to give some attention to this  issues.

**Addendum:**
If your table is longer than one page (as you noted in your comment below), than in above MWE you need to do the following:

- remove `table` environment
- `tblr` replace with `longtblr`
- insert caption and labels in `longtblr` options (see MWE below)
- caption style define on the `tabularray` way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}   % not used in longtblr or talltblr
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begingroup
\NewTblrTheme{CAPT}{     %or any to you meaningfull name
    \SetTblrStyle{head}{font=\small}
    \SetTblrStyle{foot}{font=\footnotesize}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
                    }
    \begin{longtblr}[
  theme = CAPT,
caption = {Full-model chemical reactions ($\mathit{vf}$: forward reaction, $\mathit{vr}$: reverse reaction)},
  label = {table:fullmodel_rxns}
                    ]{colspec = {@{} Q[l,m]
                                X[0.8, l, m]
                                X[1.2, l, m, mode=math] @{}},
                     row{1} = {font=\bfseries, mode=text, c},
                     row{3-Z} = {abovesep=5pt},
                     rowhead ) 1    % <---
                 }
    \toprule
{Chemical\\ Reaction}
    &   Description
        &   Reaction Rates    \\
    \midrule
\ce{-> sg$1$}
    &   induction of synthesis of sgRNA1 by Arabinose
        &   vf = Ara*(1-bSG1)*\mathrm{VMAX}*(30 - sg5dCasGA - sg6dCasGA)   \\
%        \midrule
\ce{-> sg$1$}
    &   basal levels of sgRNA1 w/o Arabinose
        &   vf = (bSG1)*\mathrm{VMAX}*
            (30 - sg5dCasGA - sg6dCasGA)            \\
%        \midrule
\ce{sg$i$ ->}
    &   degradation of sgRNAi   $i={1,2,3,4,5,6}$
        &   vf = (\mathrm{dmRNA\ case}F)*sgi            \\
%%%% repeated row, that can be show how longtble works
 \ce{-> sg$1$}
    &   induction of synthesis of sgRNA1 by Arabinose
        &   vf = Ara*(1-bSG1)*\mathrm{VMAX}*(30 - sg5dCasGA - sg6dCasGA)   \\
%        \midrule
\ce{-> sg$1$}
    &   basal levels of sgRNA1 w/o Arabinose
        &   vf = (bSG1)*op{VMAX}*
            (30 - sg5dCasGA - sg6dCasGA)            \\
%        \midrule
\ce{sg$i$ ->}
    &   degradation of sgRNAi   $i={1,2,3,4,5,6}$
        &   vf = (\on{dmRNA\ case}F)*sgi            \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Any ideas how I can make it span across multiple pages if the table has many rows? I saw longtable but can't seem to be able to replace tblr with it..

Comment: @MarinaPanteli, for such a table you should us some long table. For example, `tabularray` package provide `longtblr` table.. All long tables should not be enclosed in `table` float. Using any long table you should be aware, that such table can break only between rows. To answer I will add an example of `longtblr` table ASAP.

Comment: @MarinaPanteli, see addendum to answer. I also add som off-topic, but not less important note about how to write your mazh expresion.